# Determinant of lattice is $q^n$ with high probability?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, determinant, integer-lattices

Lemma: Let $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times m}$ be a uniformly random matrix and $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A})=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{Z}^{m} : \mathbf{A}^Tx\equiv\mathbf{0}\ (\text{mod }q)\rbrace$ be a lattice. Then $\text{det}(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A})) = q^n$ with high probability.

I have found this proof: If $m$ is large enough then rows of $\mathbf{A}$ are linearly independant over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ with high probability. Therefore there are $q^{m-n}$ vector of $\mathbf{Z}_q^{m}$ belonging to $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A})$ since the kernel of $\mathbf{A}$ has dimension $m-n$. From this follows that $\text{vol}(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A})) = \text{det}(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A}))=q^n$.

**Question 1** Can anybody please elaborate more on the last implication?

**Question 2** How to estimate the probability that a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times m}$ (where $m> n$) picked uniformly at random has linearly independant rows?

**Edit** Thanks to the comments Question 2 is no longer a problem.

Comment: On the second question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717363, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71288 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54246.

Comment: An observation: $\Lambda^\perp(q\mathbf A)$ is the dual lattice to $\Lambda(\mathbf A)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following argument can be made.

There are $q^{m-n}$ elements of $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A)$ modulo $q$.  Equivalently, if we take $R$ to be the hypercube 
$$
R = \{x \in \Bbb R^m : 0 < x_i < q \text{ for } i=1,\dots,m\},
$$
then the set $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A) \cap R$ contains $q^{m-n}$ elements.  It follows (this is the step I'm not sure about) that the volume of $R$ is equal to the volume of $q^{m-n}$ fundamental parallelograms of $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A)$. It follows that 
$$
\det \Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A) \cdot q^{m-n} = q^m \implies \det \Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A) = q^n.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have two questions: why is the volume of $R$ equal to $q^m$? And second If you could a bit explain the step that the volume of $R$ si equal to the volume of $q^{m−n}$ fundamental parallelograms of $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A})$. Thanks

Comment: I googled and I think I have found a proof which might put a light on the step you are not sure about (i.e. that the volume of $R$ is equal to the volume of $q^{m−n}$ fundamental parallelograms of $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A})$. Lemma 4 (2) in <https://homepages.cwi.nl/~dadush/teaching/lattices-2018/notes/lecture-2.pdf> could be used in our case

Comment: ...if the volume of span$(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A}))$ is $q^m$ which I am not sure how to show

Comment: To your first comment: $R$ is an $m$ dimensional cube, so its volume is just the $m$th power of its side-length.  Alternatively, $R$ is the parallelpiped associated with $qI$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: $\operatorname{span}(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A))$ is a linear subspace, so it doesn't make much sense to say that it has a finite, non-zero volume.  What exactly do you mean by "the volume of $\operatorname{span}(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A))$ is $q^m$"?

Comment: ad 1) isn't the side length $q-1$? If you define $R'$ as parallelpiped associated with $qI$ then I understand that the volume is $q^m$ but I don't see that $R=R'$

Comment: ad 2) I was wrong, let me re-phrase. I think that the lemma from the link says that the $\operatorname{span}(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A))$ is divided into tiles of volume $det(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A))$.  As $|\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A) \cap R|=q^{m-n}$ then $R$ contains $q^{m-n}$ tiles of volume $det(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A))$. Since volume of R is q^m then $det(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A))=q^n$

Comment: @gorte you're right; I've made a slight change which hopefully fixes things

Comment: For your second comment: I guess the point I'm having trouble with is jumping from "$R$ contains $q^{m-n}$ points of the lattice to "$R$ contains $q^{m-n}$ parallelopiped tiles".

Comment: Lemma from the link: $\forall x \in \text{span}(\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A)) \exists! y\in \Lambda^\perp(\mathbf A)$ s.t. $x\in y + P(\mathbf{B})$ where $P(\mathbf{B})$ is a parallelpiped defined by a basis $\mathbf{B}$. This tell us that the intersection of parallelopiped tiles is empty, doesn't it? And therefore there is $q^{m-n}$ parallelopiped tiles

Comment: @gorte right, because each point in the latice is the corner of exactly one tile!  Yes, I think that will work just fine.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for your help, I wouldn't manage without you